# resolv.conf always query both servers

Tags: resolv.conf

Is there any way to force resolv.conf to always query all servers for an IP? Currently if I have

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

It will try 1.1.1.1 first. If there is no response in 5 seconds then it will query 8.8.8.8. I would want it to always query both at the same time and use whichever answers first.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is a data file, and does not query anything.

Answer (score 5):

No... and yes.

"No".  The behaviour you're seeing is embedded into the library routines.  The OS will always try the servers in order, producing the behaviour you're seeing.  So `resolv.conf` can not solve this problem.

"Yes".  However... you can cheat.  You can specify a single DNS server in `resolv.conf` and *that* can perform parallel lookups on your behalf, and return the results of the first server to respond.  `dnsmasq` has the `--all-servers` option, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

You can achieve that using dnsmasq.

There's an (external) article here explaining how to do so, and how to fix it to be dnssec aware.

https://jeanbruenn.info/2017/05/28/parallel-dns-lookup-using-dnsmasq/